# Facebook.Unity.Gameroom.dll was not registered

Tags: unity-game-engine, dll, build-error, unity-webgl, facebook-gameroom

> Unity3D version 2017.1.1f1

Whenever I launch Unity, I get the following error:

> Assertion failed: Extension
>   Library/FacebookSDK/Facebook.Unity.Gameroom.dll was not registered,
>   that means it relies on default UnityExtensions settings, please
>   register extension and apply necessary settings for it in the
>   callback. I tried deleting the Library folder but the problem is still
>   there and the file Facebook.Unity.Gameroom.dll also exists.

Also when I try to build for WebGL, 3 more errors are shown and build fails. The first one is as follows:

> ArgumentException: The Assembly Facebook.Unity is referenced by
>   Facebook.Unity.Gameroom
>   ('Library/FacebookSDK/Facebook.Unity.Gameroom.dll'). But the dll is
>   not allowed to be included or could not be found. 
>   UnityEditor.AssemblyHelper.AddReferencedAssembliesRecurse
>   (System.String assemblyPath, System.Collections.Generic.List`1
>   alreadyFoundAssemblies, System.String[] allAssemblyPaths,
>   System.String[] foldersToSearch,
>   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2 cache, BuildTarget target) (at
>   C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/AssemblyHelper.cs:142) 
>   UnityEditor.AssemblyHelper.FindAssembliesReferencedBy (System.String[]
>   paths, System.String[] foldersToSearch, BuildTarget target) (at
>   C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/AssemblyHelper.cs:179) 
>   UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()

How can I solve this?